# D10 alternative long diameter

Tags: dice

Newbie here with one d10 dice related question. I am making some minis standees and I would like to use d10 dice to easily visualise health for each mini. The ones I have are of 18-20mm size (I believe this is the standard size) but I was looking for something smaller. Such as 10 mm.
Any idea if I could find anything as such?
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to RPGSE.  For the first five or six years that this site existed, a question like this was within our limited format.  Unfortunately, a few years ago a meta decision was made to stop accepting tool recommendation questions.  I am not sure if or how your basic problem to solve can be framed to leave it open, since I suspect that at least one other user has considered a similar, novel application of that Table Top RPG tool.  FWIW, [Tour], [Help], [Ask] and [Answer] provide guidance on how to get the most from an SE site.  Once again, welcome, and I hope you'll browse other Q&A here.

Comment: You've got enough rep to hop into our very own [chat] where some friendly folks can help outside of the standard stack format.

Comment: Yes, 10mm d10s exist. If you don't have a friendly local game store who's up for acting as an intermediary, you can buy them loose from dice manufacturers like Chessex (unfortunately their site store is unlinkable Javascript, but "specialty dice" -> "mini polyhedral loose" should get you there) or just search for "10mm d10" on a reseller like ebay.

Comment: Also VTR so I can make that a real answer, because "does this size of die exist as a commercial product?" is more on the product identification side of things, which is absolutely something we still do.